# How are Libraries named in xcode? How do I navigate to a specific library?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am getting an error which says - "ld: - library not found for -lpods-AppName-DZNWebViewController"
My question is NOT how to fix this error but rather to understand where xcode is looking for this library? Is there a directory where this library needs to be? Below are snapshots of my project workspace. 
[image of my project files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9V7Jg.png)

Comment: To add a library, using CocoaPods is the best way. But the other way involves copying your library files in your Xcode project and then going to build phases->Link binary with libraries->click '+' sign->Add Other, & then select your library.

Using cocoapods, you can search the library name on cocoapods.org, then copy paste the library string in a 'pod file' in your project. Then all you have to do is run 'pod install' in terminal & cocoapods takes care of all the setup work!

Comment: Hi Prasad, thank you for your answer. I'm still a bit confused on what the "library" means here. Is it a .m file, .h file, or  a .a file ? (or some combination of those?) Really appreciate your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

## Using CocoaPods to Maintain Library Dependencies

A library that supports CocoaPods will provide you with the command required to install the library. In this case, it is

> pod 'DZNWebViewController'

If this doesn't work, you can always edit the project settings manually.

## Manually Maintaining Library Dependencies

**Even when using CocoaPods, you can still edit the locations yourself. You can provide Xcode with three types of paths for where to search for files, using project settings in the Search Paths section:**

[image]

- **Framework Search Paths** refers to frameworks that are pre-compiled
- **Library Search Paths** refer to any library that you include in your project, for access from your code. These are usually the pre-compiled files that have the '.a' extension.
- **Header Search Paths** are usually used in conjunction with Library Search Paths, to tell Xcode where the headers are located for a given library.

**The error that Xcode provides will tell you which search path setting and the path it had a problem with:**

- **ld:** refers to library Search Paths
- **fd:** refers to Framework Search Paths
- **hd:** refers to Header Search Paths

**To provide a fully-qualified search path, you can can begin the path using pre-set placeholders that Xcode provides for convenience.**

The following two placeholders often refer to the same location and are therefore synonymous, by default:

- $(PROJECT_DIR) - this refers to the project root directory, where the source code is located
- $(SRCROOT) - this refers to the source root directory

To complete a path specification, you would follow with a '/', providing the full path to a directory, as in:

> $(SRCROOT)/some_dir/some_other_dir

**To provide a recursive search path, simply add two asterisks at the end of the path, as in:**

> $(SRCROOT)/some_dir/some_other_dir/**

To add multiple paths in one of the Searh Paths settings, you simply separate them with spaces:

> $(SRCROOT)/some_dir/some_other_dir $(SRCROOT)/some_dir2/some_other_dir3

---

This brings up the obvious question: *what if a path contains spaces?*

**If your path contains spaces, then wrap your path in double quotes, as in:**

> "$(SRCROOT)/some dir/some other dir/" "$(SRCROOT)/some dir2/some other dir3/"

Another option is to escape the spaces in your paths, by preceding each space with a backslash (in this case, you cannot use quotes). However, this makes it harder to read, and therefore more difficult to debug, especially when there are multiple long paths:

> $(SRCROOT)/some\ dir/some\ other\ dir/ $(SRCROOT)/some\ dir2/some\ other\ dir3/

Comment: Hi Sheamus, thanks for the answer! One question I had was - where do we specify the name of the library that is required? For example, in my project I want to use the DZNWebViewController library. The error is "library nor found for lpods-TwitBit-DZNWebViewController" I'm thinking the library may be present but may have a name other than "lpods-TwitBit_DZNWebViewController" I'd appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi @manavkothari, it looks like you're using cocoapods to configure your dependencies, since the error is pointing to lpods? Is that correct? Otherwise, I would suggest adding the path to that library to your Library Search Paths setting. Make sure you use the `SRCROOT`, followed by the location within your project. By the way, if the answer is what you were looking for, please check it as the answer!

Comment: Hi @Sheamus, yes I am using cocoapods. When I search through my .m files, I see "libDZNWebViewController.m" in a folder called "Products", which is in a folder called "Pods" in the project. Going by the information you mentioned above, xcode would be looking for a .m file correct? The problem is that the error is "library not found for lpods-TwitBit-DZNWebViewController" Why this specific name? I don't think there is a .m file for this ( for example, a lpods-TwitBit-DZNWebViewController.m). Also, I have checked it as the answer.

Comment: @manavkothari, It's not a .m file. I looked at the GitHub page for the library, and it says you can use the pod 'DZNWebViewController' to install the library and make the necessary changes. Otherwise, if that doesn't work, I would try bypassing CocoaPods, and do it manually, following the directions on that GitHub page, which says to add WebKit library (which CocoaPods would have done for you, if it wasn't already added to your project).

Comment: Hi Shaemus, I still don't understand what the name of the library is? Does the error suggest that there should be a library called "lpods-TwitBit-DZNWebViewController"? If so, how did we arrive at this name? And where is this library supposed to go? I'm sorry I've been trying to understand this for days but have not made much progress.

Comment: If you are using CocoaPods, then there is usually a directory directly under your project root directory, called Pods. Otherwise, for manual installations, you can drop a directory directly under the root, at the same level as the Pods directory. It looks like this library is called DZNWebViewController. I don't know where the TwitBit comes from. I would suggest trying to install manually from the GitHub site download, and take note of the file structure when you unzip it. The directions for manual install should be included in a readme file.

Comment: When you drag in the directory, make sure you drag it to the project navigator. Then, select a target, select the General tab, go to the linked frameworks and libraries section, and click on the +, and locate your Freemark directory, and add it to the project.

Comment: Hi Shaemus, thanks for your reply. Should I call the library "DZNWebViewController" or "lpods-TwitBit-DZNWebViewController" ? ( the latter is what the error says). TwitBit is the name of the App, btw.

Comment: Hi, @manavkothari DZNWebViewController seems to be what it should be called, according to the GitHub page.